# Arithmetic question about percentages

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Hi I have a rather basic arithmetic question about percentages which is confusing me:

Let's say you have a variable x that is composed of x1, x2, x3.

You know what (x1 + x2) is, and you also calculated from some other data that x3 is y% of x. How do you now adjust (x1+x2) to get x?

So for example:

(x1+x2)= 55

Y%= .31

Which of the following two is the correct answer for x?

55*(1+.31)   OR   55/(1-.31)

The first one you're adding 31% to the 55, but in the second one you assume that the 55 is 69% of x, and so to get 100% you divide 55/.69.

Which is the right one?

Comment: The second one is correct. $\dfrac{55}{0.69}$

Comment: Thanks much! When is the first answer ever correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By

> $x_3$ is $y\%$ of $x$

I assume you mean that $x_3$ is $y\%$ of the sum of $x$ (i.e., $x=x_1+x_2+x_3$).

---

In that case, you know that $x_1+x_2$ is $(1-y)\%$ of the total sum (in your example, that would be $0.69$.

So you have $55=0.69\cdot x$ or $$x=\frac{55}{0.69}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: How come yours was voted down?

Comment: @sqlfiddler No idea why it was downvoted. The downvoter has the right to do it, although the usual way is to *tell* the poster why you think the answer deserves a downvote. I'll live, though.

Comment: I have a follow up question: say you have a ratio of x/y, and you know the value of y, and you now want to increase y by x/y, would you in this case do the following y*(1+(x/y))?

Comment: Pressed enter before giving example:

Comment: @sqlfiddler Depends on what "increase by x/y" means. But yes, for example, to increse $y$ by $5\%$, you need to multiply it by $(1+0.05)$.

Comment: So: y =55; Ratio of x/y=.3, I.e for every 1 unit of y, there's .3 units of x (is that correct interpretation?) so, to increase y by that amount I would multiply y*1.31, is that correct? If not, when is this method ever correct? Thank you

Comment: I guess by increase I mean to get the sum of x+y.

Comment: @sqlfiddler I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, let me try and explain. I know the value of x1, and I want to get x=x1+x2. I have some other data that's given me an indication that the ratio of x2/x1 is .31. So what I did is, to get x1+x2, I multiplied x1*(1.31). Based on your answer I guess that wrong. But Doesn't the x2/x1 ratio tell me that x is 31% more than x1? That's why I did the multiplication. Thanks..

Comment: If you know that $\frac{x_2}{x_1}=0.31$, and you know what $x_1$ is, then you know that $x_1=0.31\cdot x_1$.

Comment: Oh thank you!  this means my answer (55*1.31) was right...huge relief :) have a nice day!